# Class 'DOMPDF' not found after downloading via Composer

Tags: php

I used Composer to download the latest (V0.7).
I copied the entire downloaded 'vendor' directory to my web server, but get the error:
 **class DOMPDF not found**

If I change it to use namespaces I get the error **'Fatal Error Call to undefined function DOMPDF()'**

Several hours trying desperately to find what is missing. I never had any problems using Composer before, (it usually takes care of all the dependencies), but obviously not in this case!
Any ideas will be greatly appreciated.

```
Sample Code:

<?php

require "../vendor/autoload.php";

$dompdf =\DOMPDF(); // previously used new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->loadHtml($html);
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream("sample.pdf", array("Attachment"=>0));

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved it myself..
in case anyone is interested the example given on the Github page is missing  CRITICAL line

I added: **use Dompdf\Dompdf;** and that fixed it.

```
require "../vendor/autoload.php";

use Dompdf\Dompdf;

$dompdf =\DOMPDF(); // previously used new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->loadHtml($html);
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream("sample.pdf", array("Attachment"=>0));
```